# Android app save image path then retrieve it from database

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to do for each customer and destination should have a photo by saving the path of this photo in the database in order to retrieve it again.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.pr;

import ItemsAndDatabase.Destination_Item;
import ItemsAndDatabase.Flight_Item;
import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddDestination extends Activity {

    private int customer_id;
    private string name;
    private int passportNo;
    private int ID;
    private string addr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.add_new_destination);

        final EditText txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText CusID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText Pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        final EditText photo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        final EditText Addr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);

        Button btnAddNewcustomer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(AddDestination.this,
                        destination.class);
                AddDestination.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });




        btnAddNewcustomer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!txtName.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                        && !CusID.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                        && !Pass.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Destination_Item item = new Destination_Item();
                    item.setName(txtName.getText().toString());
                    item.setCountry(CusID.getText().toString() );
                    item.setLongg(Pass.getText().toString() );
                    item.setLatt(photo.getText().toString() );
                    item.setPhoto(Addr.getText().toString() );

                    MainActivity.db.addDestination(item);
                    Toast.makeText(AddDestination.this,
                            "Destination Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    finish();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(AddDestination.this, "Please Fill All fields",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

And this is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Country"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Long"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lat" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Photo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Add Destination" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button2"
         android:layout_width="126dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:text="back" />

</LinearLayout>
```

any idea how to do this ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the issue?  Is the data not getting saved in the database the way you expect?

Comment: i am try to give the user photo from mobile then save the photo path into sqllite database in order to retrieve it pls help me in code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to let the user take a photo during the sign up? 
you should change the photo into an ImageView instead of using EditText.

If you are going let the user take a picture or use an image from gallery,  use the developer in android or use Androidhive.com

Comment: Try this one.
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/23/store-image-android-sqlite-retrieve-it/

Comment: I am willing to help.